# Matrix Multiplication (Same dimension)

Tags: matrices

How do you multiply two of the same matrix with same dimension like example below? Do I need to transverse the second matrix or dot product?

3x1 * 3x1

$$
[1,2,3]*[4,5,6]\\
[4,5,6]*[1,2,3]
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strictly speaking not defined.

The definition of matrix multiplication of two matrices $AB$ requires $A$ is of size $m$ by $p$ and $B$ is of size $p$ by $n$ and the produce is of size $m$ by $n$.

In some programming language such as Python, it might be defined as the dot product when you deal with $2$ vectors.

Comment: If we are dealing with 2 vectors how would I solve this?

Comment: It is not defined... are you dealing with a programming language? If so, which language?

Comment: No I dealing with just basic vectros, For example the above I know how to find find dot product is that dot product the i or j or z value? The answer is express. Not sure if the question is correct or wrong. I

Comment: dot product for two real column vectors can be written as $u^Tv$. dot product of two real row vectors can be written as $uv^T$. notation wise, we do write it as $\langle u, v \rangle$.